# Problems with php in the atom-editor

Tags: php, atom-editor

I've installed the Atom editor recently on my Ubuntu 14.04, all fine but I have some problems with php files: auto-completion and linting just does not work for php. I've tried all php auto-completion and linting packages but all the same. With js and python I don't have such problems and all works great. And here is the error which I recently got in the Atom:

```
Error: PHP Notice: Undefined offset: 92 in /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/Tokenizers/PHP.php on line 646 PHP
Stack trace: PHP 1. {main}() /usr/bin/phpcs:0
PHP 2. PHP_CodeSniffer_CLI->runphpcs() /usr/bin/phpcs:25
PHP 3. PHP_CodeSniffer_CLI->process() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/CLI.php:95
PHP 4. PHP_CodeSniffer->processFile() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/CLI.php:892
PHP 5. PHP_CodeSniffer->_processFile() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer.php:1715
PHP 6. PHP_CodeSniffer_File->start() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer.php:1837
PHP 7. PHP_CodeSniffer_File->_parse() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/File.php:471
PHP 8. PHP_CodeSniffer_File::tokenizeString() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/File.php:689
PHP 9. PHP_CodeSniffer_Tokenizers_PHP->tokenizeString() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/File.php:1429
```

Comment: Have you tried `linter-php`? That one works just fine for me.

Comment: Yes I've tried that one too. As I said I've tried all of them but none works.